# ERROR ITMS-9000 xcode app submission error

Tags: xcode, binary, submit, app-store-connect

I got this error when I tried to submit the binary to itunesconnect.
I re-created and refreshed the provisioning profile, clean the project, delete the drived data from disk, restart the xcode.  I did everything I can think of, but I still get this error.

The binary submitted to itunesconnect before, then the app got rejected, I fixed the bug and need to re-submit the app.  I could not find ready to submit binary button anymore on itunesconnect, I figured I will just submit the binary from my xcode anyway.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day struggled about this issue.  I found out for the rejected app when you resubmit the fix, you will have to change the app id setting from developer portal to unselect the Associated Domains.  Then you will need to update the provisioning profile on both developed portal and the xcode.   After that, I successfully submitted the app to itunesconnect.

[image]